# Sometimes focus moves to first tab in TabControl when closed a dialog in another app domain

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a strange and challenging problem. I have a TabControl with two tabs. When second tab is shown, users could open a dialog with a mouse click. However, this dialog is in another app domain because of some reasons. When users close the dialog, sometimes the focus moves to the first tab, it causes that second tab is hidden and the first tab is shown.

Any help are highly appreciated.

Best regards,
Alex

Comment: are you working with the tab controls SelectedItem or SelectedIndex property at all?

Comment: And dou you jandle the Activate event? Or better: look for any code that changes the TabIndex.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there's some code running when the second window is closed. Can't really make guesses at random though, without seeing a single line of code; anything can happen, basically, but it's most likely there's some user code that triggers the action, it shouldn't happen from built-in behavior.